# Why my find('a') doesn't work in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function in jquery:

function handleUpcomingUserTexts () {

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'getjson.php', 
    type: "POST",
    data: {
        mail: '<?php echo htmlentities($_SESSION["email"]); ?>'
    },
    dataType:'text',
    success: function(ans)
    {
        var data = JSON.parse(ans);

        $.each(data, function(i, v) {

            var upcomingText = $('<a href="#" class="list-group-item"><i class="fa fa-comment fa-fw"></i> '+v.Content+'<span class="pull-right text-muted small"><em>'+v.Date+'</em></span></a>');


            $('#upcomingTexts').append(upcomingText);


            var a = upcomingText.find('a').on('click',function(e){

                e.preventDefault();
                alert("here");


            });

            });     

}});

};
```

and it fills the html nicely, but when I click the link - nothing happens and I don't see the alert message. What is wrong in here?

Comment: because `upcomingText` has no descendant anchor

Comment: man, it's not secure to pass php code from client, I can eval everything at your server))
I mean this: 
`mail: '<?php echo htmlentities($_SESSION["email"]); ?>'`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because `upcomingText` is already a `a`. And you are trying to find a `a` in your `a`.

You can just write this :

```
var a = upcomingText.on('click',function(e){
```

When you write `var variable = $('<a ...>...</a>');`, the result is the root tag of the given html. So in your case, the `<a>`.

Answer (score 2):

Because `upcomingText` is `<a>` and in this tag there are not any `<a>` tags, so you need use `upcomingText` like this

```
upcomingText.on('click',function(e) {});
```

but [`event delegation`](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) in this case better solution

```
// add this code before $.ajax
$('#upcomingTexts').on('click', 'a.list-group-item', function(e) {});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `delegate` function, on  `#upcomingTexts` block

```
$('#upcomingTexts').delegate('a', 'click', function(e){
    //your code here
});
```